# Custom UIView's labels not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have custom UIView that has a xib file as well as .h and .m files. My custom view contains a number of UILabels.

I have added this view to a UIViewController's xib file by dragging in a UIView, going to the Identity Inspector and changing the class name to MyCustomView. MyCustomView is connected the the view controller with an IBOutlet property.

When the view controller is loaded, the MyCustomView's

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
```

method is called, but none of its labels show in the view controller's view. How can I fix this?

I already know how to add a custom UIView through code using:

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" 
                                                     owner:self 
                                                   options:nil];
MyCustomView *view = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

but I want to know how to add through the xib file. I have searched for a while but haven't been able to find the answer, so if this is a duplicate please point me towards the correct answer.

---

Here are images of the custom view xib and the view controller xib:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you go into IB's identity inspector and change the class for the viewController as well (not just the view)?

Comment: Darren, include an image of your IB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid You can not make UIViewController's xib load your own view's xib.
You'll either need to add those labels into you own view programly,

or

add the view into your viewcontroller's view programmly, as you showed in the code

Comment: That looks like it is the case. Can you provide a link to some documentation discussing this? Otherwise I'll leave this question unanswered for a little while in the hopes that someone can provide a solution.

Comment: If it's possible, i think you'll be able to specify the view's xib in the view controller's xib. For example, you can let a UITabBarController load your own viewcontroller from the xib file for its tab

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see more code to know for certain, but I suspect that the problem you are having is that the custom view (the parent of the UILabels) is not giving the UILabels dimensions. It's not calling -[UIView setFrame:]

To verify that, type this in the debugger:

```
po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

That will print a description of the view hierarchy. Check what the frames of the UILbals are.

Comment: If I use po [_myCustomView recursiveDescription] I get (id) $2 = 0x0a665e50 <MyCustomView: 0xa4f23f0; frame = (10 35; 300 126); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa6654e0>>. The labels don't seem to be there.